# Execute code that deferred function depends on while waiting

Tags: javascript, settimeout

In the minimal example below, the replacement of old content is deferred by `setTimeout` to give the user time to finish viewing it. In the meantime, new content is being prepared so as to avoid blocking the user interface during a potentially expensive task.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var newContent = document.createElement('ul');

setTimeout(function() {
  var header = div.firstElementChild;
  header.innerHTML = 'New Content';
  header.nextElementSibling.remove();
  div.appendChild(newContent);
}, 2000);

// Make new content while we wait
[1, 10, 100, 1000].forEach(function(x) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = 'Factorial of ' + x + ' is ' + factorial(x);
  newContent.appendChild(li);
});

function factorial(num) {
  if (num === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return (num * factorial(num - 1));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <h1>Old content</h1>
  <p>Read it before it's gone.</p>
</div>
```

My concern with this approach is that it does not seem to handle `newContent` not being ready when the replacement is due to take place. I am also uncertain if this approach will block the user interface or if the task used by `setTimeout` will be executed concurrently.

How can I ensure that the user interface is not blocked while executing a potentially expensive task and immediately using it upon completion?

Comment: If your `newContent` is being prepared by some synchronous methods and you are certain about the availability of the content after `timeout`, there is no harm doing it this way..

Comment: Find out the time. Generate the content. Find out the time again. If less than 2 seconds have passed, wait the remainder of the time and then replace. Otherwise, replace the content immediately.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.  Maybe incorporate fade in/fade out so the change of content is not so subtle

Comment: 1000 factorial is way past the ability of JS to represent numbers. Anyway, "whether this is advisable" is a user experience question, not a programming question, unless you are asking if your particular implementation is an advisable approach. And why would you ever **not** need to worry about `newContent` not being ready?

Comment: @torazaburo (1) I was indeed asking whether my implementation was the right approach. Judging by the responses I got, most people seemed to understand. (2) I personally worry about `newContent` not being ready (hence the question), but I can imagine a language implementation where that would never be a problem, thus making my worry moot. I don't know whether JS is like that, hence the question. (3) The factorial calculation is just an example of potentially expensive operations and therefore hardly relevant.

Comment: In what language implementation, other than a quantum computer, could an arbitrarily long computation not have the potential to take more than *n* seconds?

Comment: @torazaburo In my hypothetical language, if Function X is still running at time t when Function Y is scheduled to run, then Function Y queues up and waits for Function X to finish. I'm not saying this is a good design, and I don't know if any languages are like this (I'm a novice, remember?), but it's possible.

Comment: Your language is not hypothetical. It's called JavaScript, and the language mechanism to accomplish what you want is called "promises". But you have to invoke them; they do not happen magically, not do they make something finish before it does, nor alter the immutable fact that if you want something to be done or ready, then it has to be done or ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two requirements:

1. Do not hide the introduction until at least 2 seconds have passed.
2. Do not hide the introduction until the content is ready.

The changes below satisfy that.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <h1>Old content</h1>
  <p>Read it before it's gone.</p>
</div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var newContent = document.createElement('ul');
var contentReady = false;
var timesUp = false;

function onContentReady() {
  if (! timesUp || ! contentReady) return;
  var header = div.firstElementChild;
  header.innerHTML = 'New Content';
  header.nextElementSibling.remove();
  div.appendChild(newContent);
}

setTimeout(function() { 
    timesUp = true;
    onContentReady();
  } , 2000);

function makeContent() {
    // Make new content while we wait
    [1, 10, 100, 1000].forEach(function(x) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = 'Factorial of ' + x + ' is ' + factorial(x);
      newContent.appendChild(li);
    });
    contentReady = true;
    onContentReady();
}

function factorial(num) {
  if (num === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return (num * factorial(num - 1));
  }
}

setTimeout(function() { 
    makeContent();
  } , 4000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the time value in this code to be less than 2 seconds and more than two seconds to see that.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    makeContent();
  } , 4000);
```

Comment: I accept the answer to thank you for your effort, but the solution @Mike McCaughan suggested in comments is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I think `contentReady = true; onContentReady();` should be after the loop it's currently in.

Answer (score 9):

Your long-running computation is going to block the browser, which is never a good idea. Therefore, you should put it in a web worker.

These days it is better practice to write asynchronous code with asynchronous tools such as promises. Here's a general, pseudo-code level approach:

```
// Create a promise which fulfills after some # of ms.
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Create the worker, kick it off, and 
// return a promise which fulfills when the worker reports a result.
function waitWorker() {
  const worker = new Worker('factorial.js');
  worker.postMessage([1, 10, 100, 1000]);

  return new Promise(resolve => 
    worker.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data))
  );
}

// Wait for both the worker to complete and the two seconds to elapse.
// Then output the data.
Promise.all([timeout(2000), waitWorker()])
  .then(values => output(values[1]);
```

Writing the worker is left as an exercise.

#### Using async functions

You could also express this a bit more cleanly using async functions, if your environment supports it, as follows:

```
async function calcAndWait() {
  const result = waitWorker(); // Kick off computation.
  await timeout(ms);           // Wait for two seconds.
  output(await result);        // Wait for computation to finish and output.
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, I wish that advertisers would use this type of approach more often, as their computation constantly locks the browser window during load.